# schunk_svh_driver : How I can read current position?

Tags: ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to read current position and the value of current at every instant to control the grasps online. Can you help me? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208010/schunk_svh_driver-:-how-i-can-read-current-position?/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-27**:
channel_feedback (sensor_msgs/JointState)

```
Current position of the channels (fingers).
```

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-27**:
Yes, I know that I can use channel_feedback, but I don't know how I can use it, because I try calling:
rostopic echo svh_controller/channel_feedback and it prints messages to screen, but how I can use the current data to update the channel_targets?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-27**:
you could send it with "rostopic pub ..."  or write a node which publishes to channel_targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. I solved my problem, I can read the current position calling:

```
rostopic echo svh_controller/channel_feedback
```

---

Originally posted by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) with karma: 20 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0